# how to sort data table data that is displayed in gridview

Tags: asp.net, sorting, session, gridview, datatable

*Page 1:(the following is the Code incorporated in button click. When i click on button of page 1 should display the table data in page 2)*

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s="select * from items";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(s,con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        Session["a"]=dt;
        Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx");
    }
```

*page 2 :(Code for displaying the table data in page 2)*

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DataTable dt=(DataTable)Session["a"];
       GridView1.DataSource = dt;
       GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Now may i know how to sort the data displayed in gridview at run time?

Answer (score 0):

`GridView` allows users to sort using `AllowSorting` property. Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowsorting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).